# Take information from a text area and display it on separate page or put it in an array (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

For example I have a (feedback area) on my website, its a text area, when users type into this area and click a button, I would like Javascript to take thier information and write it to a feedback blank oage or place it in an array which I can use for a feedback update area

Any ideas thoughts??

Answer (score 0):

This is what forms are designed to do. You are probably going to need a middle tier app like php, asp or coldfusion .

Answer (score 0):

Using some server side scripting such as ASP, PHP etc as **invertedSpear** suggests will be the easiest way, would strongly suggest looking at the tutorials over at w3Schools or Tizag for code snippets.

Alternatively if your web hosting provider does not support server side programming (it's rare but some don't) then there may  be a way using a Javascript / AJAX call and Yahoo Pipes to store the data and use JSON to display. However this is a method of last resort being way more complicated than a simple PHP form.